# SQLite best way to save and traverse arrays of strings

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that looks like this.

```
   | id | coords |
   |  0 | [1,0],[4,3],[4,9],[9,3],[1,8]     
   |  1 | [3,6],[3,8],[7,4],[5,2],[2,1]
   .. and more
```

There will be around 70k-100k rows at most, and the CPU is not very powerful.

**What is the fastest and least cpu intensive SQLite statement i can use to determine which id has any given coordinate? No two id's share a coordinate.**

Example.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE coords LIKE '%[[]3,8]%'
```

I imagine the LIKE statement above will get pretty intensive right?

Comment: Can't you change the database structure?

Comment: Yes, what kind of structure is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always try to have a properly [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) database.

In this case, the coordinate list is not in the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).
If you move the coordinates to a separate table, you can search for coordinates with a simple and obvious query, which can be be sped up with an index:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID,
    [...]
);
CREATE TABLE MyCoordinates (
    MyTableID,
    CoordX,
    CoordY
);

SELECT MyTableID FROM MyCoordinates WHERE X = ? AND Y = ?;
```